# Can I use caulking to install a marble threshold?

Tags: adhesive, caulking, marble

I have a black marble threshold that I'd like to install in my bathroom doorway. Is it OK to use caulk to adhere it to the floor, or perhaps liquid nails? Or is this not recommended?

If not what is the easiest adhesive to use for this?

Answer (score 3):

The easy thing to do would be Liquid Nails and I am pretty sure they have a stone version.  A better solution would be some thinset.

I do not agree with silicone because it has a little give in it.  After a while of kicking or stepping on it will lose its grip a bit and eventually come loose.

Comment: Hmm. Fair point.

Comment: If you use LiquidNails brand, make sure you get the stuff for stone.   LiquidNails expands while it cures, and could lead to the threshold not sitting quite right.

Comment: As @Tester101 says make sure it is the stone stuff.  Also for all thresholds I do with liquid nails I set a towel then weights on it overnight.  I had a couple issues of the thresholds setting a little uneven or even lateral movement and the weights (3 x 45 pound plates) basically have cured all.

Comment: I have the same problem here, I can't use thinset because of the extra thickness so I'm thinking on using a PU adhesive (used in constructions) or maybe an epoxy compound (used to bind screws to concrete). From what I've seem on the Liquid Nails website, they are PU based, right?

Answer (score 0):

Silicone caulk is generally used to adhere marble countertops to cabinets, so I would imagine that it would serve just fine for your application.